# send phone number through emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, phone-number

I am making an application and I want to retrieve the device phone number and send that on the server. But I am testing this application on android emulator. Can anybody please tell me how to set or get the phone number in emulator and actual device.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't get the phone number on real device. On emulators, they're the ports. For example `emulator:5554`, then the phone number is `5554`.

Comment: My impression is that you can get the phone number, but just not always. It depends on the state of the telephony subsystem and its connection to the network if you can obtain the phone number by calling TelephonyManager.getLine1Number().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the phone number in emulator if we use the Telephony manager

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String phone = tm.getLine1Number();

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
```

On making the toast of the phone number we get the phone number like..
`15555215554`

It also need the android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission.
So Emulator is also having its own phone number.

Answer (score 0):

In **DDMS** perspective You will see **Emulator Control** tab you can emulate the call from there. 
If you don't see Emulator Control there . Use Window> Show /View > Emulator Control to make the tab appear.

To accesss device phone number in your code use telephonymanager.getLine1Number();
You need to set READ_PHONE_STATE permission in manifest file for that.

Comment: In emulator control we can only make an incoming call to emulator but we can't get the device own phone number.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call the emulator from your device. But you can make calls to two emulators. For details on how to ? you can go to DDMS perspective then  Emulator Control tab you can make the call from there to other emulator.
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Comment: I am not talking about calling to the emulator. I want to retrieve the actual phone number of the emulator.

Comment: actual phone number of emulator can be seen on emulator it would be 4 digit number ex:- 5544 or 5546