# Android Eclipse Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, phone-number

Need Help -> I want to get phone number and show it, I have code like this

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);    
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();    
TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVphone);    
t.setText(mPhoneNumber);
```

but nothing result, so I check my Android emulator with setting-phone-status-phone number show 'unknown', how to change it? I want my phone number not unknowm.
Thanks

Comment: emulator should not have any phone number, returning `unknown` is correct, try to test it on a real phone. your code should have no prob returning the number.

Comment: i don't think there is a telephone in your emulator

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a phone number to the emulator and try the above code.

Comment: how to add a phone number in emulator ??

Comment: Sorry,I misunderstood your problem.I thought you need to display the phone no.s in your contacts.So I answered like that.But I think your real question is how to get the device owner's phone no.AFAIK emulator doesn't contain any phone no.So try this code in some android phone.

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599346/send-phone-number-through-emulator) for more info.

"In DDMS perspective You will see Emulator Control tab you can emulate the call from there. If you don't see Emulator Control there . Use Window> Show /View > Emulator Control to make the tab appear."

Also you need the android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission in your manifest, do you have that?